# How can I open textual sites in emacs?

Tags: emacs, web

I would like to know how to open sites in emacs. Websites with plain HTML without many graphics!! Is there a mode that I must set??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Ahem, two ways to do that:

1 - Setup and use Emacs-w3m, a text browser written in Lisp http://w3m.sourceforge.net/

2 - Launch a shell in your Emacs and use Links, Lynx or another text browser. (M-x eshell)

Answer (score 3):

You want to look into using either [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) or [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/). There are emacs modes available for both.

Comment: I don't know the difference between them. I want the simplest, because I think in use this only for simple things in order to try gain some productivity. Which one would be best?